# Type of numerical semigroups is not bounded when embedding dimension is $\geq 4$

Tags: nt.number-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

I am currently studying numerical semigroups. I know that there is no upper bound for the type of a numerical semigroup with embedding dimension greater or equal than $4$. There is a famous example by Backelin of a numerical semigroups with dimension $4$ and unbounded type: pick $n\geq 2$, $r\geq 3n+2$ and $s=r(3n+s)+3$ and let
$$H=H_{n.r}=\langle s,s+3,s+3n+1,s+3n+2\rangle.$$
According to Fröberg, R., Gottlieb, C., Häggkvist, R.: in their article "On numerical semigroups" (Semigroup Forum), the set $$M=\{(r+1)s+i \: | \: -2\leq i\leq 3n-1, i\neq 0 \pmod{3}\}$$
is a subset of the set of pseudo-Frobenius numbers of $H$, and as $|M|=2n+2$, the type of $H$ is unbounded. **I want to prove that $M$ is actually a subset of $\text{PF}(H)$**.

In their article, Fröberg, Gottlieb and Häggkvist suggest how to do this. First, we have to prove that if $s\in H$ and $x<(r+2)s$, then $x$ is a sum of exactly $\lfloor \frac{x}{s}\rfloor$ generators. I know how to prove that it is the sum of at most $\lfloor \frac{x}{s}\rfloor$ generators, but not the "exactly" part. I guess I have to use $x<(r+2)s$ here, but I don't know how to do this, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Assuming this is true, I am able to prove that $M\cap S=\emptyset$. However, I still have some trouble checking that $M+x\in H$ for every generator $x$ of $H$.

**Edit**: I managed to prove that if $x<(r+2)s$ then it is the sum of of exactly $\lfloor \frac{x}{s}\rfloor$ generators. Now I am only having trouble with checking that $M+x\in H$ for every generator $x$ of $H$.